# Winodw.close() in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a usercontrol where i want to open a error window to display error messages. I have used the window.open in ascx.cs, the window opened correctly.
Now i want to close the opened window by calling another method where i am using window.close().
It is not working for me. Please help me on this.
Note: when i debugged using IE debugger, It shows 'ErrorWindow' undefined

```
public void ShowMessage()
{
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    string script = "var ErrorWindow = window.open('Sample.aspx', 'MyWindow', '').focus();";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "Script", script, true);
}


public override void CloseWindow()
{
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    string script = "var ErrorWindow; if(ErrorWindow != null){";
    script += "ErrorWindow.close();}";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "Error_Script", script, true);
}
```

Comment: `ErrorWindow` is actually undefined because you're using `var ErrorWindow;` in the second function, which will create a new undefined variable. Try passing the first `ErrorWindow` as an argument to the close function.

Comment: You are redefining `ErrorWindow`, `var ErrorWindow; if ...`

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner i am calling the methods from aspx page, Is it possible to pass ErrorWindow as argument

Comment: @Arg0n when i use ErrorWindow in CloseErrorWindow() directly, it returns ErrorWindow undefined

Comment: @Naveen Since you override the `StartupScript`, I would say: No, not in your approach.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Is there any other way to close the window using javascript in code behind??

Comment: @Naveen You could define both functions in the first JavaScript script, then call the open function and in the close C# function call the second one, but I don't exactly know how you would achieve this.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks a lot.. i tried your suggestion. But i couldn't make it work